# Где скачать файл с интернета? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

допустим есть такой код:

```
url = 'https://test/test.com/file.exe'
fileName = 'c://dir/dir/dir/test.file'
req = requests.get(url)
file = open(fileName, 'wb')
for chunk in req.iter_content(100000):
    file.write(chunk)
file.close()

print("DONE!")
```

он скачивает файлы с сайтов и он работает, но как загрузить свой файл на какой-либо сайт чтоб он его мог скачать? проблема в том что данный код не скачивает файлы с github, есть ли другие источники куда можно загрузить свои файлы чтоб программа могла их скачать?

Comment: непонятно. Если этот код работает, то о чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: вопрос в том, где захостить файл чтоб его можно было скачать

Comment: тогда почему заголовке "как", а не "где" или "куда"?

Comment: хорошо, исправил, а теперь обясните куда можно закинуть файл чтоб можно было его скачать с помощью данного кода

Comment: понятия не имею. чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, нужно закачать куда-то файл и проверить. А заниматься этим мне неохота. Да и вряд ли вообще у кого-то есть такое желание.

Comment: Сайт, куда можно загрузить файл, чтобы потом его скачать, называется "файловый хостинг". Чтобы можно было загружать и сохранять файлы с помощью кода, у хостинга должна быть штука, которая называется "API". Соответственно, вам нужно просто вбить в поисковик "файловый хостинг с API", поизучать результаты, и выбрать, что больше понравится.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, вы ничего никуда не можете загрузить

Для того, чтобы загрузить свой файл на какой-либо сайт в интернет нужно, чтобы вы были хозяином сайта или чтобы хозяин сайта разрешил вам загружать файлы на его сайт

Но так как файлы занимают место и если все будут загружать информацию на ваш сайт, то у вас закончится место и ваш сайт больше работать не будет

Поэтому, обычно разрешают сохранять у себя файлы за деньги или показывают вам рекламу, но и в этом случае, код работать не будет

Попробуйте `Яндекс диск`

Comment: Яндекс диск не совместим с данным кодом

Comment: @Selasi понятно, жаль